# How can you find $P(\frac{X}{Y-X}<0)$ if $X\sim Geometric(p)$ and $Y\sim Bernoulli(p)$

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

Let the independent random variables $X\sim Geometric(p)$ and $Y\sim Bernoulli(p)$, I want to prove that $P(\dfrac{X}{Y-X}<0)=(p-1)^{2}(p+1)$.

Do I need the joint probability mass function for this or should it be proven in some other way?

Any help or hints will be appreciated

Comment: Just condition on the value of $Y$.

Comment: Strange exercise, where they train you to neglect divisions by zero...

Comment: I don't quite understand what you meant by that, Did... (sorry) Where is the division by 0?

Comment: Y-X, what else? (Unrelated: Please use @.)

Comment: @Did Yes, I see you mean the case where $X=Y$. I probably didn't ask you the right question. I'll try to explain myself better: when is X equal to Y? is it for certain values of $p$? would you suggest any corrections on the exercise?

Comment: Note that X and Y are **random variables** hence the trouble is that $P(X=Y)\ne0$ (but apparently this is not a problem to you since you accepted an answer - so I guess everything is fine?).

Comment: @Did Thanks. That's something new to me. Now I understand why it's a problem. So, would you say the answer $(p-1)^{2}(p+1)$ is not technically correct? (even though Alijah's post was useful because it helped me to understand the general procedure)

Comment: Even before that, I would never ask such an exercise to my students. Rather, asking for $P(X<Y-X;Y-X>0)+P(X>Y-X;Y-X<0)$ would be perfectly rigorous. Then the answer is $P(Y>2X)+P(Y<X)=1-P(Y=0)P(X=0)-P(Y=1)P(X=1)$, which you can probably compute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that $Y$ is Bernoulli distributed, it will have probability mass function $P(Y=0)=(1-p)$ and $P(Y=1)=p$. As Frank has helpfully commented, we can condition on $Y$.

When $Y=0$, we have $P(\frac{X}{Y-X}<0|Y=0)=P(-X<0|Y=0)=P(X>0|Y=0)$

When $Y=1$, we $P(\frac{X}{Y-X}<0|Y=1)=P(\frac{X}{1-X}<0|Y=1)=P(X>1|Y=1)$

Thus, we have the following (the third line being a consequence of the independence between $X$ and $Y$)
$$\begin{align}P\left(\frac{X}{Y-X}<0\right)&=P\left(\frac{X}{Y-X}<0|Y=0\right)P(Y=0)+P\left(\frac{X}{Y-X}<0|Y=1\right)P(Y=1)\\&=P(X>0|Y=0)P(Y=0)+P(X>1|Y=1)P(Y=1)\\&=P(X>0)P(Y=0)+P(X>1)P(Y=1)\\&=\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}p(1-p)^k\right)(1-p)+\left(\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}p(1-p)^k\right)(p)\\&=(1-p)^2+p(1-p)^2\\&=(p-1)^2(1+p)\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you very much, Alijah (and Frank)! That's very helpful and illustrative. It's much clearer now

Comment: You are welcome.