# Can anyone recommend good books on (transformation of) random variables and distributions?

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

I'm currently self-studying and I'm looking for books focusing on random variables and their transformations, which possibly contain examples like the one in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1245513/how-can-you-find-p-fracxy-x0-if-x-sim-geometricp-and-y-sim-bernoul).

I'm also interested in convolution of distributions.

Any books you've read and would recommend? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handbook on Statistical Distributions for Experimentalists - University of Stockholm

A link to the pdf http://www.stat.rice.edu/~dobelman/textfiles/DistributionsHandbook.pdf

Cambridge University posts lectures notes and homework online.  You could visit there.  There is a list of courses available here http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/teaching/1415/

Transforming Density Functions - https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/teaching/2003/Probability/prob11.pdf

---

Convultion of distributions

Here are some lecture notes I found from MATH 526 University of Washington
Lecture 8 will focus upon convolution.  This link will take you to all the lectures and homework.

http://www.math.washington.edu/~hart/m526/

http://www.math.washington.edu/~hart/m526/Lecture8.pdf

University of Manchester - Products and Convolutions of Gaussian Probability Density Functions

http://www.tina-vision.net/docs/memos/2003-003.pdf

---

If you could be more specific I am sure I could find more.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your contribution. Those webpages look very interesting. More specifically, I'm looking for examples of how to find, for example, things like $P(X>Y)$ or $P(X^Y\leq X)$ or $E(1/X)$ for different distributions.

Comment: What do you mean by X > Y?  As in conditional probabilities like the likelihood of X given probability of Y.  Try looking for state transition matrices and markov chains.  Are you looking for multidimensional distributions?

Comment: I mean $P(X>Y)$ where $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables. In short, I'm looking for examples of how to compute probabilities (or the mean, variance, etc.) of a function of a random variable, if that makes sense.  (Thanks for mentioning Markov chains, by the way. I'll look into that as well).

Comment: I found a very good explained example of markov chains which are essentially what I think you are looking for.  More importantly they can utilize as many independent random variables at time.  They can be constrained to two variables like X and Y is you choose. http://www.dartmouth.edu/~chance/teaching_aids/books_articles/probability_book/Chapter11.pdf

Comment: Thanks a lot :). That document looks interesting too.